# How to make axes appear when using Show to combine plots?

Tags: plotting, graphics

The following code results in coordinate axes not showing up. I'd like to understand why that happens and how to fix it. Ideally, there's a way to do it so that I can set the image size and axis parameters once and separately from the plotting code.

```
g = Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}];
g = Show[g,
Table[
ParametricPlot[{(1 + t) Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
 AxesStyle -> {{Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]}, {Black, 
    AbsoluteThickness[5]}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, AbsoluteThickness[12]}],
{t, 0, 1, 1/5}]
];
Magnify[g, .25]
```

Comment: `coordinate axes not showing up` will adding `Axes -> True` to the `Show` command do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

The use of [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) is not necessary since [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) can handle multiple plots, i.e., you can move the [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) inside the `ParametricPlot`.

```
g = ParametricPlot[
   Table[{(1 + t) Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {t, 0, 1, 1/5}],
   {a, 0, 2 π},
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[12]],
   PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]],
   ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}];

Magnify[g, .25]
```

[image]

If you do use `Show`, move the appropriate options from the `ParametricPlot` to the `Show`.

```
g = Show[
   Table[
    ParametricPlot[{(1 + t) Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, 2 π},
     PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[12]]],
    {t, 0, 1, 1/5}],
   PlotRange -> {{-2.1, 2.1}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]],
   ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}];

Magnify[g, .25]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't like this solution because the setting of the ImageSize, axes, etc. begins to float around various parts of the code. Is there a solution where the common attributes of the figure (size, axes, background, aspect ratio, etc.)  are set up front and then various pieces of the plot (curves, points, etc.) are introduced afterwards.

Comment: @Wynne - I do not understand what you are looking for, The first solution above puts all the options in a single `ParametricPlot`; there is nothing floating around and no decisions to be made as to which option goes where.

Comment: It's in a ParametricPlot. I want it logically divorced from plotting. The problem with putting it in a ParametricPlot is that if I later decide to insert some element before the parametric plot, then all these settings will no longer be at the top and I'll have to cut them out of the ParametricPlot and insert them into whatever I choose to preceed the parametric plot.

Comment: @Wynne - Perhaps you want [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html)